# python: recreating system process tree from ps command in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, process, ps, pstree

I'm new to python and I'm trying to recreating in a python dictionary the processes hierarchy like the unix pstree does.

Unfortunately I cannot use the wonderful psutil library cause I don't have permissions to search into /proc path.

Did somebody already done this exercise ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run pstree you can use subprocess:

```
from subprocess import check_output


out = check_output(["pstree","-u","foo"])
print(out)
```

Comment: I cannot use pstree since I need all system processes informations and I have only sudo permissions for "ps" command as root.